# Unable to renew SSL certificate using apache2 at ubuntu (aws ec2) instance

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-ec2, godaddy-api

The website was running fine with GoDaddy's SSL installed, it has been approx a month since SSL expired and I lost the CSR file we used for the SSL certificate first time.

**Steps I tried:**

1. Created new CSR files as follows, in directory `/etc/apache2/ssl`

   `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout mysite.com.key -out mysite.com.csr`
2. Using the new CSR code generated a new SSL certificate at GoDaddy, downloaded zip, and moved to the server having 3 files in it.
3. Moved all files at `/etc/apache2/ssl`, now this directory has 5 files as follows.

   ```
   -rw------- root:root mysite.com.key
   -rw------- root:root mysite.com.csr
   -rw-r--r-- root:root 0000000000.crt
   -rw-r--r-- root:root 0000000000.pem
   -rw-r--r-- root:root gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
   ```
4. Updated my VirtualHost as under.

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.mysite.com
        ServerAlias *.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/public

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/0000000000.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

        <Directory /var/www/html/mysite/public/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

5. Run successfully following commands.

   ```
   sudo a2dissite mysite-ssl.conf
   sudo a2ensite mysite-ssl.conf
   sudo systemctl reload apache2
   ```
6. Checked by running following command on the server, it is loading the correct certificate.

   ```
   openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
   ```

The issue is website is not getting a new SSL, still getting an old validity period.
[image]

**More Attempts:**
Tried to install the free SSL certificate, but this domain is still getting GoDaddy old expired certificate in the browsers :-(

**Latest Findings:**
In GoDaddy panel there are 2 entries for **A RECORD** as follows, I am not sure if this is the issue?

```
Type    Host        Points to
A       @           PROXIED
A       starkip     123.123.123.123
```